# using tcpdump to display XML API requests without headers or ack packets

Tags: linux, centos5, tcpdump

I need assistance, I am trying to use tcpdump in order to capture API requests and responses between two servers, so far I have the following command:

```
tcpdump -iany -tpnAXs0 host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and port 6666
```

My problem is, that the output is still hard to read, because it sends the Headers, and the ack packets.

I would like to remove those and only see the XML bodies.

I tried to use grep -v, but apparently this is all one request, so it filters the entire thing...

Thanks!

Comment: TCPdumpt only dumps the network layer data, not applicaiton layer. so you have to wireshark to convert the tcpdump data to readable form.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$ while read stream; do \
tshark -qz follow,tcp,ascii,$stream -r soap.pcap; done \
< <(tshark -R "xml" -T fields -e tcp.stream -r soap.pcap | sort | uniq)
```

Source: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/18046/extracting-segmented-soap-xml-payload

Comment: hmmm, this doesnt work, I get error:
tshark: The file "soap.pcap" doesn't exist.

I understand you got it from that script where PCAP=$HOME/tmp/sample.pcap, but I am not sure how to adapt this to my situation... I dont have pcap file, I am trying to capture from a live stream.

Comment: Update: I think I understand what you meant after trying taking the script apart:

tcpdump -iany -tpnAXs0 port 6666 | while read stream; do tshark -qz follow,tcp,ascii,stream -r soap.pcap;


But this generates errors like:
tshark: invalid -z argument.

Comment: Why not write the raw packets to a pcap file using `-w`, then you can filter them? `tshark -v`?

Comment: if you could please give me a complete example of the full filter command, I would try.